# Python3 beautifulsoup doesn't parse anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.sahibinden.com/hyundai/"
req = requests.get(url)
context = req.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(context, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

I am getting an error with the above code. If I try to parse another website it works, but there is a problem with sahibinden.com . When i run the program it is waiting like 1 minute than it throws an error. I ve to parse this website. Could you please help me with explaining what the issue is?

Comment: Hey Hakan, welcome to SO! Could you add the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the server is expecting a user agent, can't perform the request without it.

It's possible that the error that's giving to you is a timeout?

Add the following to your code

```
headers_dict = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers_dict)
```